# Using CSS fonts in Flex

Tags: css, apache-flex, fonts, flex4, embed

For a Flex application I'm writing, I will be using the same custom font on the website hosting the app and the app itself. I don't want the client to download the font twice, so is there a way to embed the font in standard webpage CSS and use it in Flex (or vica versa)?

Edit: I know how to embed a font into Flex. However, right now, I'm embedding the same font twice - once into CSS and another time into Flex. This feels redundant to me.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=flex%20external%20font

Comment: I know how to embed a font into Flex. However, right now, I'm embedding the same font twice - once into CSS and another time into Flex. This feels redundant to me.

Comment: The only way out, here, seems to be to rely on the browser to cache the font (does it do that for HTML?) I haven't done much w/custom fonts in Flash, but if you don't embed it and the font is in the cache, Flash should use it from the cache.